# Compiling file.c and creating executable file with one button - Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: compiling, 19.10, c, executable

I'm wondering if there is a way (e.g. a software like bloodshed dev c++ in Windows) to compile a file.c and to create the executable file by using a single click.

I know only the classic way: writing code in gedit and save it as file.c, writing the code "gcc file.c -o file" in the terminal, and finally writing " \ .file" in the terminal.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May be Code::blocks?

Comment: The default rules for `make` allow you to compile and link a single C or C++ source file `file.c` or `file.cpp` straight to an executable just by typing `make file`. The `./file` step (which is what I assume you mean by " \ .file") then runs the program - it's is nothing to do with making it executable.

Comment: Hello @steeldriver, does i need 2 line in the terminal to use the command "make file"? The first "gcc..." and the second "make file"?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi `make file` looks for a source file called `file.c` and runs `gcc` for you to produce the executable `file`

Comment: Hi @Kulfy thank you for your suggestion; it is what I am looking for.